# Querying DynamoDB on non-key attributes

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to filter DynamoDB queries using non-key attributes in AWS version 2 ?  Amazon says that they can do it: http://amzn.to/1FVgQ9B.  But do they also give the API?  I found AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression, but I think it only lets filtering on the range key (not enough documentation).  I'm looking for the proper API in iOS and AWS version 2.  Thanks!

Comment: In order to [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), you **must** provide the hashKey. You can then use a [filter expression[(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults) on any other attributes to filter down your results.

Comment: I haven't found the API to do that in iOS.  It seems there's none.  I know that in theory as they say in the documentation that you sent that it is possible.  Note that that document is platform independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.  This is what I posted on AWS support forum as well:

You can't do this with the high level API -- AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper. When using AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper, you need to provide an AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression object to the query method to specify the query conditions. AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression doesn't give you the option to set filters(conditions) on non-key attributes. I wonder why this isn't supported! However, AWSDynamoDBScanExpression lets you specify conditions on non-key attributes when you use the scan method. But you don't want to scan when you actually mean a query.

Fortunately, you can do this using the low level API by directly calling query on AWSDynamoDB providing an AWSDynamoDBQueryInput which lets you specify a lot of low level parameters. AWSDynamoDBQueryInput lets you specify the filter conditions on non-key attributes using either queryFilter or filterExpression. queryFilter is deprecated, it's recommended to use filterExpression. 
Here are the two documents that helped me to figure this out:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBQueryInput.html

Here's a code example in swift.  In this code I'm filtering based on "approved" field that is a non-key attribute. recId is the primary key:

```
    func getApprovedRecords(recId: Int) {



     let dynamoDB = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()

        var startKey = nil

        var queryInput = AWSDynamoDBQueryInput()

        queryInput.tableName = TABLE_NAME

        queryInput.limit = QUERY_SIZE

        queryInput.exclusiveStartKey = startKey



        var recIdValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()

        recIdValue.N = String(recId)

        var recIdCondition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()

        recIdCondition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ

        recIdCondition.attributeValueList = [recIdValue]



        queryInput.keyConditions = [ "recId"\" : recIdCondition]


        var oneValue = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()

        oneValue.N = "1"



        queryInput.expressionAttributeValues = [ ":one" : oneValue ]    

        queryInput.filterExpression = "approved = :one"

        dynamoDB.query(queryInput).continueWithBlock { (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in

            if ((task.error) != nil) {

                NSLog("The request failed. Error: \(task.error)")

            }

            if ((task.exception) != nil) {

                NSLog("The request failed. Exception: \(task.exception)")

            }

            if ((task.result) != nil) {

                NSLog("The request  succeeded.")

                let results = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBQueryOutput

                for r in results.items {

                    // do whatever with the result

                }

            }

            return nil

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code as well that how you achieved this functionality?