# Dynamodb table query on non hash key

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am using dynamodb in c#.

I able to do scan for all records. But the requirement is to do query on non-key columns, but I am not able to get it,

I found this link [Querying DynamoDB on non-key attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138094/querying-dynamodb-on-non-key-attributes), but cannot get it

It would be better if i could get any link or any sample

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: Its using secondary index for query, I want to query on other columns that are not used in index or key

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up with this solution

```
 Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.Condition cond = new Condition();
            cond.ComparisonOperator = "EQ";
            cond.AttributeValueList = new List<AttributeValue>() { new AttributeValue { S = "ColumnValue" /*Media.ConvertToTimestamp(twoWeeksAgoDate).ToString()*/ } };
            ScanResponse scRes = client.Scan(new ScanRequest { TableName = "TableName", ScanFilter = new Dictionary<string, Condition>() { { "ColumnName", cond } } });
```

Comment: That is not a `Query` in DynamoDB terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to clarify that [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) requires at least the Hash key with an equality condition. You'll need to do a [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) to filter across hash key values.

For Query, you can also specify a [FilterExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-FilterExpression) to put conditions on non-key attributes, but be aware that this is applied on the results of the Query conditions (i.e. no performance benefit in terms of number of items that are processed in DynamoDB, but can reduce what's sent over the network and gives you the convenience of not having to do it client-side).